# How to load zsh/mapfile in ZSH

Tags: macos, homebrew, zsh

I have installed zsh version 5.6.2 via brew. I am having trouble loading mapfile module.

adding `zmodload zsh/mapfile mapfile` gives error `~/.zshrc:15: failed to load module 'mapfile': dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.6.2_1/lib/mapfile.bundle, 9): image not found`

Anyone know how to debug this or a fix ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To load the `zsh/mapfile` module, just run

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
```

You can check that it's correctly loaded with:

```
zmodload
```

You should then see the following list of loaded modules:

```
zsh/complete
zsh/main
zsh/mapfile
zsh/parameter
zsh/zle
zsh/zutil
```

You can then use it, for example, such as:

```
# Define a file named pp with three lines
echo yay1 >> pp                                                                     
echo yay2 >> pp
echo yay3 >> pp

# Build the associative array
arr=("${(f@)mapfile[pp]}")

# Show the content
echo $arr[1]
echo $arr[2]
echo $arr[3]
```

For explanation about the mapfile module see [ZSH Gem #22: Accessing and editing files with mapfile](https://www.refining-linux.org/archives/57-ZSH-Gem-22-Accessing-and-editing-files-with-mapfile.html).

For details about the Parameter Expansion Flags see the corresponding section in the [Zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

Comment: yeah, zmodload is able to load the module. The problem is that mapfile is still not available in zsh.

Comment: @Moulick @chovy `mapfile` is available but not in the same way as in bash, see my updated answer and the related links.